# Compare two folders and update changes

Tags: comparison, data-transfer

I recently replaced a dying server for a client and migrated all of his stuff to a NAS.

While I was copying data he and his employees were making changes on the server.

I have the bulk of the data but I would like to compare the root folder of the server with the root folder of the NAS and update the files that were changed.

Primarily the QuickBooks data.

Comment: Use rsync on Linux, robocopy on Windows

Comment: Free file sync should do what you want.